# fputs array inside for (C)

Tags: c, arrays, fputs

I'm trying to write inside a file the whole content of an array. Here is my code:

```
   fichier = fopen(patch, "w+");

if (fichier != NULL)
{
        if(methode==1)
        {
            trieur(tableau, ttableau);
            int d;
            d=0;
            for (d = 0 ; d < ttableau ; d++)
            {
                fputs(tableau[d], fichier);
            }

        }
        else if(methode==2)
        {
            trieur2(tableau, ttableau);
            int d;
            d=0;
            for (d = 0 ; d < ttableau ; d++)
            {
                fputs(tableau[d], fichier);
            }

        }
        else
        {
        printf("Methode non disponible!\nBye Bye!");
        exit(0);
        }

    do
    {
        caractere = fgetc(fichier);
        printf("%c", caractere);
    } while (caractere != EOF);

    fclose(fichier);

}
else
{
    printf("Hum something wrong witch file %s", name);
}
```

But it isn't working. Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

ps: More script, all is working normally, but my script shutting down when he should write on the file :/

main => pastebin.com/m2AM0080 
func.h => pastebin.com/KQkAbwin

Comment: Please, show the declaration of `tableau` and `fichier`. **EDIT:** and `ttableau`.

Comment: `fputs` puts a STRING. `int fputs (const char * str, FILE * stream);`. Did you mean to convert the numbers to strings and then store them into a file?

Comment: A little bit more information, please: what is tableau, ttableau etc.? What exaclty do you mean by ''it isn't working''?

Comment: Here is the whole script: main => pastebin.com/m2AM0080 func.h => pastebin.com/KQkAbwin

ttableau mean array size (number of case in the array) and tableau is the name of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Following your link to the complete code, you have `int tableau[]`. So ypu pass an `int` to `fputs()` but `fputs()` expects a `char *`. That cannot work. To write the int binarily to the output file you could use

```
fwrite( tableau+d, sizeof(int), 1, fichier );
```

To write a number of ASCII digits you could use

```
fprintf( fichier, "%d", tableau[d] );
```

Btw. it's really easier if you include declarations of the variables you use in your post directly.

Comment: Yeah i forgot it :/Thank you